# List Column Names if the value change from max is within certain % (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies for unclear title. My data look like this. They always sum to 1

```
>df
 A    B    C    D    E
 0.3 0.3  0.05  0.2  0.05
```

What i want to do it identify columns which:

1) Highest value

2) The % reduction for highest was less than threshold.

For example:
Assuming 50% was threshold, I want to end up with [A,B,C], based on logic that:

1) A & B have highest value.

2) 50% of A or B is 0.15. Since D is 0.2, it is added to list

3) 50% of D is 0.1. Since both C or E are less than 0.1, they are not added to list.

Comment: what did you try so far? Welcome to stack overflow, this goes a little bit into the direction of code writing service, any ideas from your side? Where did you stuck?

Comment: not really related to the question, but you example data doesn't sum to 1

Answer (score 0):

I used the following test DataFrame:

```
     A    B     C    D     E
0  0.3  0.3  0.05  0.2  0.05
1  0.5  0.1  0.20  0.1  0.10
```

Start from defining the following function to get column names for the current row:

```
def getCols(row, threshold):
    s = row.sort_values(ascending=False)
    currVal = 0.0
    lst = []
    for key, grp in s.groupby(s, sort=False):
        if len(lst) > 0 and key < currVal * threshold:
            break
        currVal = key
        lst.extend(grp.index.sort_values().tolist())
    return lst
```

Then apply it:

```
df['cols'] = df.apply(getCols, axis=1, threshold = 0.5)
```

The result is:

```
     A    B     C    D     E       cols
0  0.3  0.3  0.05  0.2  0.05  [A, B, D]
1  0.5  0.1  0.20  0.1  0.10        [A]
```